# React Native List with Map Method add New Item below selected Item

Tags: react-native

React Native List with Map Method

What I want to achieve,
I want when click item then a new Item (I preferer add a new custom View) is added below the Selected item.

> Expo Snack code>
> https://snack.expo.dev/@stefanosalexandrou/tenacious-french-fries

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are changing the background of the selected item, it is necessary that you update the ID's of every item in the list, for otherwise inserting elements will break this functionality. Furthermore, you need to add a state for for otherwise you cannot trigger a UI change

You could implement the desired behaviour as follows.

```js
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(persons)

  function handleOnPress(idx) {
    setSelectedId(idx)
    const first = data.slice(0, idx + 1);
    const second = data.slice(idx + 1).map(p => ({...p, id: Number(p.id) + 1}));
    setData([...first, {id: idx + 2, name: "Whatever new iten"}, ...second])
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View>

          {data.map((person, index) => {

            const backgroundColor = index === selectedId ? "#6e3b6e" : "#f9c2ff";

            return (
              <TouchableOpacity 
              onPress={() => handleOnPress(index)}
              style={{
                padding:20,
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                marginBottom:20,
              }}
              >
                <Text>{person.name}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
```

Use `slice` in order to split the array into two parts. Use `map` for updating the `id` attribute of the elements in the second array. Finally, combine both parts but insert a new element between them.

[Here is an updated snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/tenacious-french-fries).

Comment: There is possibility to remove the new Item when the selected Item become unselected or if select other Item. I want the new Item appear only if the Item is selected if not then the new item disappear. Also instead of new Item Structure can create custom component only for the new Item? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are some points to consider and I'll list them here, before providing an idea of a solution:

- React Native provides performance-optimized components that handle list rendering named [`<FlatList />`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)/[`<SectionList />`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist). Use those components instead of `.map()` for rendering component lists
- You'll need to create an internal state for your list to be changed
- You need to provide a `key` prop when rendering a list of components using `.map()` or other Array methods

With minimal changes to your provided code, you can create a state to store the list and when the item is pressed you can insert a new item inside this list:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const people = [/* your list */];

export default function App() {
  const [peopleList, setPeopleList] = useState(people)
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View>

          {list.map((person, index) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity 
              onPress={() => {
                setSelectedId(person.id)
                const newPerson = {...person}; // The new item
                setPeopleList((prevList) => [...prevList.slice(0,index + 1), newPerson, ...prevList.slice(index + 1)])
              }}
              style={{
                padding:20,
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                marginBottom:20,
              }}
              >
                <Text>{person.name}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding:20
  }
});
```

Sandbox with working code: https://snack.expo.dev/5rvTbrEvO

Comment: I don't understand your code above.  I tried it but it doesn't work. I prefer map() because it is more flexible for what I have in mind.

Comment: `FlatList`/`SectionList` are equally flexible and have performance improvements. If possible, read the docs. I also added an exposanbox link with an example of the solution.